# WSL closes unexpectedly after pressing gc key sequence

Tags: bash, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu bash as WSL on Windows 10 version 1903. I use zsh as my ubuntu shell + oh-my-zsh framework. Here is my `~/.zshrc` file (comments removed):

```bsh
export ZSH="/home/thesetj/.oh-my-zsh"

ZSH_THEME="geoffgarside"

plugins=(
  git
  zsh-dircolors-solarized
  fast-syntax-highlighting
  history-search-multi-word
  zsh-autosuggestions
  zsh-completions
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

alias ez="vim ~/.zshrc"
alias sz="source ~/.zshrc"

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

. /usr/share/autojump/autojump.sh
```

When I enter the **gc** key sequence (aliased for `git commit -v` by git plugin) in the terminal, it closes (or maybe crashes, I have no idea) the Ubuntu bash immediately:

[image]

As you see in the gif above, as soon as I press **c** after a **g**, it closes and even doesn't print it in the terminal. Beware that I did use Hyper terminal for this gif, but I also tried the original ubuntu.exe which comes by installing the distro.

I need to clarify that this only happens if the key sequence is entered in an empty line. I mean if I enter something like **agc** or **some-command gc**, nothing abnormal will happen.

I know my question may seem stupid, but I'm really confused about it. I even don't know how to google it properly (multiple tries failed to give me any related result).

Comment: Can you reproduce that same issue with a minimal fresh installation of any distribution and without using any terminal (that is only wsl.exe)?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I've tested the key sequence on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS bash on another computer of mine. Nothing happens.
By the way, your question leads me to think about my zsh configuration. Thus, I'll edit my question ASAP to add the content of my .zshrc file.

Comment: @Biswapriyo By disabling all plugins and re-enabling the one by one I found out that there is a conflict with git plugin and fast-syntax-highlighting plugin which causes the issue. With the default configuration of oh-my-zsh and only enabling fast-syntax-highlighting alongside with git, the behavior happens.